# What is a cyclic group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, cyclic-groups

I cannot seem to wrap my head around cyclic groups. I need this explained in layman's terms because this seems to be a big part of Modern Algebra, and its confusing me with other stuff. I know that,
a group is cyclic if there exist an $a \in G$ such that every element of $G$ is a power of $a$. We write $G=\langle a \rangle$ or $a$ is a generator of $G$.

So for example, would $\mathbb{Z}_6$ be a cyclic group? $\mathbb{Z}$ is a group under addition, so it has generators $\langle 1 \rangle = \langle 5 \rangle$. So, would that make $\langle1 \rangle=\langle 5 \rangle$ cyclic subgroups, therefore $\mathbb{Z}_6$ is a cyclic group?

Answer (score 1):

We are going to make it geometric.

Let's first cover finite cyclic groups.  A cyclic group of finite order $N$ is the group of rotations, in the $xy$-plane, about the origin by the following angles:
$$
{2 \pi k \over N}, \quad k = 0, 1, 2, \ldots, N-1.
$$
In such a group, if we take the (smallest nontrivial) rotation, $k=1$, which rotates the plane by the angle
$$
{2 \pi \over N},
$$
all other rotations in the group can be obtained by repeating this one.  That's how this rotation *generates* all the others.  This rotation is general not the only generator.

Sketch the rotations for $N=4$: these rotate the plane through quarters of a full turn.  Study what they do to a square with vertices $(1,1), (-1,1), (-1,-1), (1,-1)$.  (The "preserve" this square.)

Now return to your example: $N=6$.  What polygons are preserved by the rotations in this cyclic group?  Try multiples of rotation $k=5$.  Do these multiples give us the entire group?  Why about the multiples of rotation $k=3$?

And if the cyclic group is infinite, it is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$.  It shifts the real line by multiples of integers.  What generators does this group have?

Answer (score 1):

You're absolutely right! A group is cyclic if it has an element that generates the group. In the case of $\Bbb Z_6,$ you've found the two possible generators, though we should probably think in terms of multiples (vs. powers), since we're dealing with commutative groups.

Another way to think about it--which gets around distinctions like multiples vs. powers--is this:

- Given a group $G,$ let $\mathscr{S}(G)$ indicate the set of subgroups of $G$. For example, $G$ and the trivial subgroup (with just the identity of $G$) will be elements of $\mathscr{S}(G).$
- Given any set $\mathscr A\subseteq \mathscr S(G),$ if $\mathscr A$ is non-empty, then we can prove that $\bigcap\mathscr A\in\mathscr S(G)$ using the subgroup test.
- Given any subset $A$ of $G,$ we define $\langle A\rangle:=\bigcap\bigl\{S\in\mathscr{S}(G):A\subseteq S\bigr\}.$ By the above, $\langle A\rangle$ is the smallest subgroup of $G$ containing $A$ as a subset.
- When considering sets of the form $\{a\}$ for $a\in G,$ we will typically use $\langle  a\rangle$ to mean the same thing as $\bigl\langle\{a\}\bigr\rangle,$ just because it looks nicer. Similarly, we'll do the same thing for other finite sets. From that perspective, saying that there is some $a$ such that $\langle a\rangle=G$ means that no proper subgroup of $G$ has $a$ as an element, because the whole group $G$ is the closure of $\{a\}$ under the group operation, inverses, and identity.

Answer (score 1):

Actually a cyclic group is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ for some $n=1,2\dots$ or it is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$(you may think this as the case $n=0$).
  Note that $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z},+)$ is a cyclic group of order $n$, since it is generated by $\overline{1}$. As you may have noticed, this generator is not unique, in fact $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z},+)$ has $\varphi(n)$ generators. For instance  $$\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}=\{\overline{0},\overline{1},\dots,\overline{5}\}=\{\overline{0},\overline{1},\overline{1}+\overline{1},\dots, \overline{1}+\overline{1}+\overline{1}+\overline{1}+\overline{1}\}$$
 $$\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}=\{\overline{0},\overline{-1},\dots,\overline{-5}\}=\{\overline{0},\overline{5},\overline{5}+\overline{5},\dots, \overline{5}+\overline{5}+\overline{5}+\overline{5}+\overline{5}\}$$
In the case of $\mathbb{Z}$, this has only two generators, $1$ and $-1$, because other number, say $2$ for instance, this would only generate multiples of $2$, i.e. even numbers.